# why this combining Array formula and countif in google sheet not working?

Tags: array-formulas, countif

i have a data that need to countif.. but a long one data and much..

so i try to use `arrayformula(countif(oFFSET(M2:M;0;0;1;15);"Benar"))` and its not working..

can you guys help me.. plis i still have 10 more like this.. thx before

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1klBmiNIhMiRjNawDST9Cp85uVzRnU2S3xxvu1ScKq5M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

en G2

```
=ArrayFormula({mmult(IF(H2:V=G1;1;0);transpose(column(H2:V)^0))})
```

you need to use mmult